# How do I correctly require and declare node library typings in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, definitelytyped

I am trying to write a package for node in TypeScript that uses standard node libraries, for example `fs`, `path`, `stream`, `http`, and so on.

When I try to import libraries in a .ts file, VS Code marks the corresponding line with an error:
`[ts] Cannot find module 'fs'`.
This happens no matter how I try to import the library:

```typescript
import * as fs from 'fs';    // [ts] Cannot find module 'fs'
import fs = require('fs');   // [ts] Cannot find module 'fs'
const fs = require('fs');    // [ts] Cannot find name 'require'
```

[image]

I (should) have the correct definitions installed with `typings install --save --ambient node`.

When I compile to JavaScript (using `gulp` and `gulp-typescript`, not `tsc`), the compliation **works** and the **syntax highlighting shows no errors** until I type in 1 character again:

[image]

**How can I correctly define the node libraries for TypeScript?**

---

I use VS Code for code highlighting and autocompletion, `gulp` & `gulp-typescript` to compile and `typings` for the typescript library declarations.

The project's directory structure:

```
├─ build/
│  └─ (output files)
├─ src/
│  └─ myfile.ts
├─ typings/
│  ├─ browser/
│  │  └─ ambient/
│  │     └─ node/
│  │        └─ index.d.ts
│  ├─ main/
│  │  └─ ambient/
│  │     └─ node/
│  │        └─ index.d.ts
│  ├─ browser.d.ts
│  └─ main.d.ts
├─ gulpfile.js
├─ package.json
├─ tsconfig.json
└─ typings.json
```

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": true,
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "target": "es5"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/browser",
        "typings/browser.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

My `typings.json`:

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "node": "registry:dt/node#4.0.0+20160412142033"
  }
}
```

And my gulp task:

```
gulp.task('build-typescript', () => {
    const gulpts = require('gulp-typescript');
    const tsProject = gulpts.createProject('tsconfig.json', {
        typescript: require('typescript'),
        outFile: 'mylibrary.js',
        noLib: true
    });

    let tsstream = (
        gulp.src([
            'node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts',
            'typings/main.d.ts',
            'src/sharpscript.ts'])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(gulpts(tsProject))
    );

    return require('merge2')(
        tsstream.dts.pipe(gulp.dest('build')),
        tsstream.js
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', { includeContent: true }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
    );
});
```

In case anyone has experienced the same problem, I am thankful for any insights.

Comment: What is the result of `tsc` command?

Comment: If you are using older versions of VSCode you have to run "Reload Typescript Project" command in VSCode.

Comment: @alisabzevari I am not using `tsc` to compile since I compile the project to `mylibrary.js` and the tests (in the same folders) to `mylibrary.tests.js`, which is not possible with `tsc`. I use `gulp-typescript`.

Comment: "Reload Typescript Project" and reopening VS Code does not fix this

Comment: Just run `tsc` to test if the project could compile correctly or not.

Comment: I think you should have module: 'commonjs' to be able to run your app in nodejs

Comment: running `tsc` complains about `Promise` being used, and because of `noEmitOnError: true` does not output any .js files

Comment: @Amid typescript does not compile to one file (`outFile` in `tsconfig.json`) with `"module": "commonjs"`

Comment: if you do want to have one file - use namespaces and still I recommend to target commonjs - as this is the modules loader standard used by node.

Comment: `error TS6082: Only 'amd' and 'system' modules are supported alongside --outFile.` Changing the output module system has nothing to do with VS Code not finding the library definitions, and therefore nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I just tried out the issue reported in my project. Could not reproduce. I had added a simple project today which uses Node and typescript. Can you clone the project and check if the problem persists in that as well? https://github.com/rmchndrng/XprssNg2TSSeed 
My Visual Studio Code version details
Version 1.0.0
Commit fa6d0f03813dfb9df4589c30121e9fcffa8a8ec8
Date 2016-04-13T14:08:36.599Z
Shell 0.35.6
Renderer 45.0.2454.85
Node 4.1.1

Comment: @LeonAdler I had this problem exactly.  Changing from 'amd' to 'commonjs' resolved the errors reported from Visual Studio code, but left me in a position where I could not use tsc to produce a single file.  If you've resolved your own issue, it would be great if you'd share your approach.  Thanks!

Comment: @KenGregory which TypeScript version are you using? This was six months ago, and might be easier with TS2. I can write an answer in the next days.

Comment: @LeonAdler I'm using 2.0.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the installation of type declarations with 'typings install ...' is obsolete since a few months. The new way is to install it directly via npm and the @types namespace. to install the node type declarations just use `npm install @types/node --save-dev`.